# There is a Thick line in the mesh, making a slight bulge and I can't do anything about it

Tags: mesh, materials

Hi I pretty much just started 3D and I was following the blender guru's tutorials making a cup.(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBtDix7xGOg) I thought I was done so I saved and was about to exit when I discovered this problem. I don't know how it happened but I did some searching and tried merging and dissolving vertices. I looked like a bunch of vertices jammed up in two spots so I even tried dragging some out and deleting them but none seems to work without breaking the object. Do I just have to redo it? is there a soluton?

[image: The thick line in edit mode]

[image: Shaded flat in object mode for easy-seeing]

Comment: maybe merge the vertices?

Comment: The culprit edge is darker than the rest. Means there might be double the vertices there. right click > merge > by distance in edit mode

Comment: I have tried merging the vertices and It doesn't seem to work